# create view similar to another one

Tags: python, django

I have to make some changes in a django project and though I'm familiar with python, I'm not with django.

This is my situation:

I have a table with the field "active". What I need to do is to let the users to sort the table based on the value of the field (yes/no).

I looked into views.py and I realized that there is a view that sorts the table based on the id:

```
users = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

My questions are:

1. How can I make the view to sort the table based on the url parameter?
2. Do I have to create another view or can I use the same with some kind of modifications?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same view.

```
def myView(request):
   get_param = request.GET.get('my_param', 'id')
   #some more processing
   users = User.objects.order_by(get_param) #note - you dont need the `all()`

   #rest of the code here.
```

Comment: Warning: this code may be used to sort on any field of the User model, so if you have any sensitive data associated to it (for example, balance of the User's account), this view may be used to get some indirect information on it. Moreover, `order_by` may span ForeignKey relationships and so this code may be used to guess the structure of your DB. You should check the value of `get_param` before passing it to `order_by`.

Comment: That does not necessarily make the answer wrong.Also, the answer provides a general idea - not the complete solution. The OP can figure out how he wants to implement it

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to render in your template. If both views will render similar html the it's probably better refactor them in a generic view and do the sorting depending on `GET` parameters.

I like separation of concerns, so another approach may be refactoring the view code inside a helper function and just call it inside each view with separated urls.

If the views doesn't render similar html and are different from each other in every aspect except that they sort something in some place, then I think the best way is to code both view separately.

It's just a consideration problem but answering your question you can get `GET` params accessing the `request.GET` or `request.POST` depending on the method.

Hope it helps!